# Issue with If/Elseif Statement in for loop when using cookies (javascript)

Tags: javascript, if-statement, for-loop, cookies

Hi in my javascript game i use cookies to load some data when the game starts

```
function loadData(){
cookieArray = document.cookie.split(';');
for (var i = 0; i < cookieArray.length; i++){
    cookie = cookieArray[i].split('=')[0];
    value = cookieArray[i].split('=')[1];


    if (cookie=="currentR"){

        round = value;

    }
    else if(cookie=="blueWins"){
        bWins=value

    }
    else if(cookie == "redWins"){
        rWins=value

    }

   }
}
```

When this is called the for loop works fine but the if statement is doing nothing?
I tried putting a console.log(cookie) right after the cookie = cookieArray line to test what cookies are being found, which are all of them including; currentR, blueWins, and redWins. but i tried putting a console.log inside each if statement but it doesn't log anything because the if statement never turns true. Why is this, because cookie does equal currentR (and the other 2) at some stage in the for loop. the console isn't logging any errors so i have no idea. and if it helps i'll include the function that saves the data then reloads the page

```
function saveData(){
clearInterval(reloadG)
document.cookie = 'currentR=' + round
window.alert("Saved Data")
document.cookie = 'blueWins='   + bWins
document.cookie = 'redWins=' + rWins
location.reload(true)
}
```

I've done some testing and i'm pretty sure the saveData function works fine. Thanks

Comment: Use `===` instead of `==`

Comment: Try `document.cookie.split('; ')` (with a whitespace added).

Comment: Thanks @Xufox ! works great now. Can you explain what the whitespace is doing?

Comment: @harrison You’re splitting it with only a semicolon as a delimiter. But the actual delimiter is a semicolon and a whitespace. You’re getting `" currentR"` as strings, not the expected `"currentR"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needed to have a white space in document.cookie.split(";")

i.e

```
document.cookie.split("; ")
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add `trim()` at the end to remove the trailing space. It works both side, head and tail.

`cookie = cookieArray[i].split('=')[0].trim();`

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to trim Your elements than guessing if it has white-space after ; or not
2. Try to make Your function modular.

You can make Your function to return object which has all data read from cookie.

Check this:

```
function loadData(){
  var data = {}; 
  var elements = document.cookie.split(';');
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
    var cookie = elements[i];
        cookie = cookie.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gm,''); // trimming whitespaces
        cookie = cookie.split('=');
        data[cookie[0]] = cookie[1];
  }

  return data;
}

var data = loadData();
alert(data.currentR, data.blueWins, data.redWins);
```